# Почему slovo после фора умножается?

Tags: c, for

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{int x, k=4;
char slovo1[5];
char slovo[5] = "pilip";
x = (int) strlen(slovo);
for (int i=0; i<x; i++){
    slovo1[i] = slovo[k];
    k--;
}
    if(strcmp(slovo, slovo1) == 0){
        printf("polin");
    }else
        printf("ne");
    return 0;
}
```

Slovo после for, пишет как pilippilip, в чём ошибка?

Comment: Ошибка в том, что ваша строка `"pilip"` содержит 6 символов, а не 5. Шестой, последний - это символ `'\0'`, признак конца строки.

Answer (score 0):

Неопределенное поведение начинается отсюда: `x = (int) strlen(slovo);`.

`strlen` ожидает на вход массив символов с хотя бы одним нулевым байтом внутри, а в вашем массиве его нет. Не влез.

`char slovo[5] = "pilip";` эквивалентно `char slovo[5] = {'p','i','l','i','p'};`. Нулевого байта тут нет.

`char slovo[] = "pilip";` эквивалентно `char slovo[6] = "pilip";` и эквивалентно `char slovo[6] = {'p','i','l','i','p','\0'};`. В конце автоматически ставится нулевой байт.

`strcmp` тоже ожидает нулевые байты, поэтому в `slovo1` его придется вставить самому.

---

Что интересно, в С++ `char slovo[5] = "pilip";` не компилируется - защита от дурака.